# ReferenceError: describe is not defined (Debugging Protractor Test)

Tags: debugging, protractor, visual-studio-code

I'm new on Protractor. So far, I have a few tests up and running on production, but I'm having a hard time chasing errors with the console logs. I have my VS Code setup for debugging and I'm getting this:

Exception has occurred: Error
**ReferenceError: describe is not defined**

```
at Object.<anonymous> (f:\My Docs\...\my-spec.js:21:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:244:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

This is what I have installed:

node --version
v6.10.2

@angular/cli: 1.3.2

protractor --version
Version 5.1.2

jasmine v2.8.0
jasmine-core v2.8.0

mocha --version
4.0.1

Here is my conf.js file:

```js
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['my-spec.js'],

  capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  onPrepare: function () {

      global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      global.defaultWait = 5000;
      global.defaultSleep = 50;
      global.takeScreenShots = false;

  },
  allScriptsTimeout: 90000,  // 90 seconds
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000     // 3 min
  }
}
```

That's supposed to be a jasmine function. It would make more sense if I get the same error while running the Test, but it's only while debugging. Since it's  the beggining of my test, I'm completly stucked. Can anybody give me at least a better clue of where this issue is? Do I need something else installed for debugging? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you only get this error while debugging? How are you debugging?

Comment: Exactly. The test runs with no issues. I'm debugging with VSCode. in my launch.json file this is the only thing I touched:"program": "${workspaceRoot}/my-spec.js",
"args": ["${workspaceRoot}/conf.js"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

The issue was in my launch file. As I said above I had this in my launch.json:
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/my-spec.js"

based on protractor website they set that to:
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",

I thought I needed to point to my test file, wrong!

So I set it to:
"program": "C:/Users/gabio/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
(where my protractor lives)

Now I can debug as normally!